# confusion about result structure from joining tables when each row has multiple correspondence on the second table

Tags: php, mysql, join, relational-database

lets say i have a simple poll aplication
and each user only can choose one option from poll

my poll table

```
+-----------+---------------------+ 
| poll_id   | question            | 
+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 | q1?                 |     
+-----------+---------------------+
|         2 | q2?                 |     
+-----------+---------------------+
|         3 | q3?                 |     
+-----------+---------------------+
```

my options table

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+ 
| option_id | poll_id             | option  | counter |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         1 | 1                   |   yes   |  254    | 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         2 | 1                   |   no    |392333337| 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|         3 | 2                   |   yes   | 1000    | 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

right now i do something like this to show all the polls i one page

```
$polls = $db->query("select * from polls ");
foreach ($polls as $poll)
{ 

  echo $poll->question;

  $options = $db->query("select * from options where poll_id = '$poll->id' ");
  foreach($options as $op )
  {
    echo '<checkbox />'.$op->option; 
  }


}
```

now if i want to do this using joine and one query

```
$query = "select p.* , o.* from polls p JOIN options  o ON p.poll_id = o.poll_id ";
```

what data structure is going to be used to represent the result ? perhaps a multidimensional array ? i'm not sure how can i printout the result

like in this example result is going to be

```
resul_array (
      poll_id  poll_question  option   option 
        1         q1            ys       no
        2         q2            no  
}
```

if i get the result as an array row one would have columns with similar name ?   i'm confused

Comment: Correction, there is no one to one in JOIN. Join match every record on the other table that matches the joined fields - it could be more than one

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you just need to add "order by" in your query, and store result in an array, and then process the logic on it.

Something like:

```
$polls = $db->query("select p.* , o.* from polls p JOIN options  o ON p.poll_id = o.poll_id order by p.poll_id");
$currentPoll = $polls[0];
foreach ($polls as $poll)
{ 
  if($poll->poll_id != $currentPoll->poll_id) {
     echo $poll->question;
     $currentPoll = $poll;
  }

  echo '<checkbox />'.$poll->option; 

}
```

HTH.